# How to get the images from cache when the app is offline by using image loader concept?

Tags: android, image, caching, offline, universal-image-loader

I am using universal image loader concept for load the images from remote server and updating to imageview.First time my application having internet connection and saving all the images on application cache("//data//cache/") memory and updating to imageview.Once the images are available in cache I would like to get the images from cache in offline not from remote server.

To get the images i have implemented following universal lazy loading concept:

```
    imageLoader.displayImage(url,imageView, options, animateListener);
```

I would like to get the same image in offline from cache.
Please give me better solution for get the images in offline loading.

Comment: Use Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide), recently google used in there iosched also as third pirty library

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution as follows:

```
 if(isConnectingToInternet()){
    imageLoader.displayImage(image_url, imageView, options);
    }
    else{
        File file = imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(image_url);
        Log.v(TAG,"file_ path :"+file.getPath());
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find Images being handled offline by efficiently using Memory and FileChache, you can view the code as [Album Sample](https://github.com/nucleartip/AlbumSample/tree/master/AlbumSample/src/main/src/com/nucleartip/album/data) this is basically a endless list representation.